# How to test lasValueFrom response and don't get message:'no elements in sequence' name:'EmptyError'

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test the `emptyBasket` method and since I upgraded the deprecated `toPromise()` to `lastValueFrom()` (rxjs 7.1.0) and I only get the error:

```
message:'no elements in sequence'
name:'EmptyError'
```

Method under test:

```
    emptyBasket(): Promise<void> {
    return lastValueFrom(this.shoppingClient.emptyBasket()).then(() => this.store.dispatch(new EmptyBasket()));
}
```

Test:

```
it('should call emptyBasket on shoppingClient', (done) => {
            mockStore.dispatch = jest.fn();
            shoppingClientMock.prototype.emptyBasket = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of());

            service.emptyBasket().then(() => {
                expect(shoppingClientMock.prototype.emptyBasket).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
                expect(mockStore.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new EmptyBasket());
                done();
            },
            (err) => { 
                console.log('error', err)
                done();
        }
            );
        });
```

Does anybody know how to workaround this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first thing I've noticed is this line:

```
shoppingClientMock.prototype.emptyBasket = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of());
```

When you use just `of()` is an equivalent of using `EMPTY`. In other words, it just emits `complete` notification and that's it. However, `lastValueFrom()` returns a Promise and a Promise needs to be resolved with a value (that's one of the core differences between RxJS Observales and Promises). So the error is correct.

You should force it to return a value with for example `of(undefined)` or `of(void 0)` even when the value doesn't matter.